# Resolving Dependencies when Creating and Installing Custom Local Anaconda Package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm developing a python package on Windows and looking to install it on a Linux machine.

I created an Anaconda package locally to port the package but I've found that installing from a local package doesn't install any of the package's dependencies, e.g., pandas, and that this might not even be possible (see https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/)

> Note
>
> Installing packages directly from the file does not resolve
>   dependencies. If your installed package does not work, it may have
>   missing dependencies that need to be resolved manually.

But isn't one of the main advantages of making an Anaconda package that it helps resolve dependencies?  How would I otherwise go about this?  Should I

1. create a requirements.txt file and provide an install_requires argument to setup() in my setup.py script and just use python setup.py install
2. export the conda environment on my windows machine via `conda env export -n my_conda_env -f environment.yml` and try to duplicate the environment on linux via `conda env create -n conda-env -f /path/to/environment.yml`
3. something else

As for how i've been creating my conda package, I've included this below.  I wasn't sure if the dependencies should be under run requirements in my meta.yaml file or somewhere else

I've been building the package via

```
conda build -c conda-forge -c anaconda .
```

Converting it to linux

```
conda convert --platform linux-64 my_package-1.0-py37_0.tar.bz2 -o ./
```

And installing it via

```
conda install --use-local my_package-1.0-py37_0.tar.bz2
```

My setup.py file and meta.yaml file are

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['tests', 'utils', 'dataprocessing'],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='me',
    author_email='',
    description=''
)
```

meta.yaml

```
{% set name = "my_package" %}
{% set version = "1.0" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  path: ..\

requirements:
  host:
    - pip
    - python
  run:
    - python
    - pandas
    - fbprophet
    - matplotlib
    - numpy
    - plotly
    - PyYAML
    - cx_Oracle

about:
  home:
```